# Password Protected on .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I am wondering about a password that I have config on a file `.htpasswd` to protect some of my web site folders.

The main problem is when I have input a valid user name and an invalid password, it can also let me in.

However, the invalid password I have input matches with the first 8 digits of my config password, I mean that the first 8 digits of the inputing password are the same the first 8 digits of the real password.

Comment: plz, put the code of your .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

This is a known limitation of crypt()

**[From apache htpasswd documentation:](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html)**

> Use crypt() encryption for passwords. This is not supported by the
>   httpd server on Windows and Netware. This algorithm limits the
>   password length to 8 characters. This algorithm is insecure by today's
>   standards. It used to be the default algorithm until version 2.2.17.
>
> When using the crypt() algorithm, note that only the first 8
>   characters of the password are used to form the password. If the
>   supplied password is longer, the extra characters will be silently
>   discarded.